# Show that $f(V_0)\cap f(V_1)\neq\emptyset$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U$ be a connected subset of $\mathbb C$ and $z_0,z_1\in U$ and if $f$ is holomorphic on $U\setminus\{z_0\}$, with essential singularity in $z_0$, prove that for any subsets $V_0,V_1$ of $U$ containing $z_0, z_1$ respectively, $f(V_0)\cap f(V_1)\neq\emptyset$

Is this by Casorati-Weierstrass ? If $f$ has an essential singularity in $z_0$ and $w_0\in\mathbb C$ is a given arbitrary value then there is a sequence $(z_n)_n$ converging to $z_0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=w_0$ and then $V_1$ need not to be an open set, it can consist only of $z_1$, right ?

Comment: what if you take $V_1=\{x_1\}$ and $V_0=\{x_0\}$ ?

Comment: You should require $V_0,V_1$  open, and it should be $f(V_0\setminus \{z_0\}) \cap f(V_1) \neq \varnothing$, since $f$ is not defined at $z_0$. Then yes, it's a consequence of Casorati-Weierstraß.

Comment: @J.E.M.S I meant only for $V_1$

Comment: @DanielFischer silly question, does image of open set must be open via holomorphism?

Comment: If $V_1 = \{z_1\}$, the intersection can be empty. If $V_1$ is such that $f(V_1)$ has at least two elements, then the intersection is not empty (assuming we require $V_0$ open, of course), but that is a much stronger assertion than you get from Casorati-Weierstraß, you need the big Picard theorem.

Comment: @J.E.M.S Unless the function is constant (on some connected component of its domain of definition), that's known as the open mapping theorem. If $f$ is constant, then the image of a non-empty set, open or not, is a singleton set, hence closed but not open.